# Hello world Cron job not working

Tags: python, unix, cron

I am only an hour into learning how [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs work, and this is what I have done so far. I’m using `crontab -e` to add my cron command, which is:

`0/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/my_username/hello.py > /home/my_username/log.txt`

`crontab -l` confirms that my command is there.

Hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Hello world python program
print "Hello World!"
```

But I don’t see anything in the log file. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that entry really on two lines, with the first line ending with `>`?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, if you edit the question, you can see it's not.

Comment: This works fine on my OS X system.  What OS are you using?

Comment: People downvoting and voting to close: It looks to me like there's a real problem here. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Your answer confirms this is a question for serverfault

Comment: @rds: More likely for superuser, or more specifically unix. I'll flag it myself.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes maybe, too. I thought superuser was more for users (like *how do I do this in Excel*). serverfault has already many questions related to crontab. But unix sounds on topic as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experiment shows that the `0/1` seems to be the problem.

`0/1` *should* be equivalent to `*`. If you replace `0/1` with `*`, it should work.

Here's my experimental crontab:

```
0/1 * * * * echo 0/1  >> cron0.log
*   * * * * echo star >> cron1.log
```

This creates `cron1.log` but not `cron0.log`.

I'll look into this and try to figure out why `0/1` isn't working, but for now just use `*` and it should work.

Update:

The `foo/bar` syntax is specific to the Vixie cron implementation, which is used by most Linux systems and by MacOS X but is not universal.

The usual way to run a command every minute is to specify just `*` in the first field. To run a command every 5 minutes, *if* your cron supports it, specify `*/5`.

Here's what the `crontab(5)` man page says:

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges. Following a range
>   with `/<number>` specifies skips of the number's value through the
>   range. For example, `0-23/2` can be used in the hours field to specify
>   command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard
>   is `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`). Steps are  also permitted after
>   an asterisk, so if you want to say "every two  hours", just use `*/2`.

I'm not even sure what `0/1` means.

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, here's what I've found.

Given that fields 2 through 5 are all `*`, setting the first field (specifying minutes) to `*` causes the job to run once a minute.  `*/2` runs every 2 minutes, and `*/3` runs every 3 minutes. This is all as expected.

Setting the first field to any of `0/1`, `0/2`, or `0/3` causes the job to run only at the top of the hour, i.e., it's equivalent to just `0`.

This is not what I would have expected from the description in the man page. The [Wikipedia quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#cite_ref-8) in [jgritty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307763/827263):

> Some versions of cron may not accept a value preceding "/" if it is
>   not a range,  such as "0". An alternative would be replacing the zero
>   with an asterisk.

doesn't seem to be entirely correct, at least for the version of Vixie cron I'm using; the `0/1` is accepted without complaint, but it doesn't mean what I'd expect and it doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: I believe the m/n syntax is an extension of Vixie Cron's, i.e. basically Linux only.

Comment: @tripleee: It looks like [MacOS X uses Vixie Cron](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html).

Comment: So it seems.  I guess the real problem is the ill-defined `0/1` like you note in your answer.

Comment: @tripleee: I'm seeing similar symptoms on my system (Linux Mint 14, Vixie cron).

Comment: For info, from ```man cron```

```[...]The cron utility then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs,
 checking each command to see if it should be run in the current minute. ```
So i guess it's impossible to run a command more than once per minute in a crontab

Answer (score 1):

`0/1` seems to be formatted wrong for your version of cron.

I found this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#cite_ref-8):

> Some versions of cron may not accept a value preceding "/" if it is not a range, 
>   such as "0". An alternative would be replacing the zero with an asterisk.

So Keith Thompson's answer should work, and so should:

`*/1 * * * *`